# Can you help me to make the functions grape and apple into a single function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

i would like to  make the functions grape and apple into one single function,because they do the same functionality  .Can you help me?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mango.css">
        <script>
             function mango(){
            document.querySelectorAll(".apple")
                .forEach(function(node){
                    node.style.display="block";
                })
             }
            function grape(){
            document.querySelectorAll(".orang")
                .forEach(function(node){
                    node.style.display="block";
                })

        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    <ul id="main" onclick="mango()">main1
         <a href="#"><li Class="apple">sub1</li></a>
         <a href="#"><li Class="apple">sub2</li></a>
         <a href="#"><li Class="apple">sub3</li></a>
    </ul>
     <ul id="main" onclick="grape()">main2
         <a href="#"><li class="orang">sub21</li></a>
         <a href="#"><li class="orang">sub22</li></a>
         <a href="#"><li class="orang">sub23</li></a>
    </ul>
</html>
```

associated CSS:

```
#main li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: none;
}
#main{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

i would like to  make the functions grape and apple into one single function,because they do the same functionality  .Can you help me?

Comment: I think perhaps you should ask at [codereview.se]

Comment: Just change  `onclick="mango()"` to  `onclick="fruit('.apple')"` and `onclick="grape()"` to `onclick="fruit('.orang')`, write the `fruit(selector)` function and use the argument as a selector. Strange fruit decisions by the way,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your class to the function as parameter.

```css
#main li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: none;
}
#main{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mango.css">
        <script>
             function mangoGrape(selector){
            document.querySelectorAll(selector)
                .forEach(function(node){
                    node.style.display="block";
                })
             }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    <ul id="main" onclick="mangoGrape('.apple')">main1
         <a href="#"><li class="apple">sub1</li></a>
         <a href="#"><li class="apple">sub2</li></a>
         <a href="#"><li class="apple">sub3</li></a>
    </ul>
     <ul id="main" onclick="mangoGrape('.orang')">main2
         <a href="#"><li class="orang">sub21</li></a>
         <a href="#"><li class="orang">sub22</li></a>
         <a href="#"><li class="orang">sub23</li></a>
    </ul>
</html>
```